# Slower azure app performance with new SQL user

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET MVC app running as an Azure app service.  It uses SQL Azure.  The app loads pages and performs database queries much slower with a new SQL user I created with `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles.  When I use the sql admin account created with the azure database, the app runs faster.  The difference is large, with the admin account, pages and searches take a second or two, with the new account it takes over 30 seconds to load those same pages.  I haven't seen this behavior on SQL server before.

I couldn't find any information on sql users and performance differences, only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285713/sql-azure-slow-performance) about SQL Azure performance.

Comment: please look into the query store and see if there are different plans being selected for the queries.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017